# Simplifying length of vector $[2\ -4]$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I understand everything until the last part where they get $\frac{2}{5} \sqrt{5}$?

I know the $\lVert [2\ -4] \rVert$  means $\sqrt{2^2 + -4^2}$

[image: enter image description here]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is right, and also you, we have in fact $|| (2,-4)||= \sqrt{2^2+(-4)^2}= \sqrt{20}=\sqrt{4•5}=2\sqrt{5}$

Comment: Holy crap I didnt even see that thank you!!!

Comment: Could you have kept it as $\frac{1}{5} \sqrt{20}$ however and be the same thing???

Comment: In this case the calculations are the same

Comment: Ok thanks thanks for the clarification

Comment: You're welcome. Good study :)